# Need port numbers to set up Azure point to site VPN behind firewall

Tags: networking, azure, azure-vpn

I have configured Azure point to site VPN properly and i could able to connect it from my home network with out any issues. Till now every things works fine.

But if i try to connect the VPN from my corporate network(office network), it always fails. I trust it is because of firewall blocking the traffic my laptop. In-order to allow the traffic i need to know what incoming ports and outgoing ports to allow traffic for the specific IP address. I know the gateway IP of the VPN. But i don't know the port numbers that i need to open in firewall.

Can any one help me to list down list of incoming ports and outgoing ports to be opened in firewall to make VPN work properly?

Thanks for advance help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the following ports need to be opened to permitting VPN traffic across a firewall, depending on the type of VPN:

**For PPTP:**
IP Protocol=TCP, TCP Port number=1723   <- Used by PPTP control path

IP Protocol=GRE (value 47)   <- Used by PPTP data path

**For L2TP:**
IP Protocol Type=UDP, UDP Port Number=500    <- Used by IKEv1 (IPSec control path)

IP Protocol Type=UDP, UDP Port Number=4500   <- Used by IKEv1 (IPSec control path)

IP Protocol Type=ESP (value 50)   <- Used by IPSec data path

**For SSTP:**
IP Protocol=TCP, TCP Port number=443   <- Used by SSTP control and data path

**For IKEv2:**
IP Protocol Type=UDP, UDP Port Number=500    <- Used by IKEv2 (IPSec control path)

IP Protocol Type=UDP, UDP Port Number=4500   <- Used by IKEv2 (IPSec control path)

IP Protocol Type=ESP (value 50)   <- Used by IPSec data path